# Regex: Get between first occurrence of one and last occurrence of another

Tags: javascript, regex, lambda

This is the string:

```
<html lang=3D"en-US"> <head> </head> <body> <div>  <script data-scope=3D"in=
boxmarkup" type=3D"application/json">
{
   "api_version": "1.0",
   "publisher": {
      "api_key": "some_api_key",
      "name": "Google Times"
   }
}
sdalfk jsdklfj slkdjf lskdjfl sjdlkf jsdlkj flsdkj flsdk jf
```

How can I get only this part?

```
{
   "api_version": "1.0",
   "publisher": {
      "api_key": "some_api_key",
      "name": "Google Times"
   }
}
```

Can't really figure out this. The plan is to parse it JSON later.

First occurrence is `{`, second is `}`.

Curly braces.

Comment: Are you sure there won't be any `{` or `}` in other places??

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, absolutely.

Comment: @tfidelis, :--(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/vXPNvM/2) might be the answer `{(?:\n|.)*}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the braces can't be somewhere else then remove all new lines and use this:

```
var partYouNeed = yourString.match(/\{.*\}/)[0];
```

**Example:**

```js
var str = 
'<html lang=3D"en-US"> <head> </head> <body> <div>  <script data-scope=3D"in=\
boxmarkup" type=3D"application/json">\
{\
   "api_version": "1.0",\
   "publisher": {\
      "api_key": "some_api_key",\
      "name": "Google Times"\
   }\
}\
sdalfk jsdklfj slkdjf lskdjfl sjdlkf jsdlkj flsdkj flsdk jf';

var result = str.replace(/\n|\r/g, '')  // remove all newlines
                .match(/\{.*\}/);       // match anything inside curly braces

if(result)
  console.log(result[0]);
else
  console.log("nothing found!");
```

Comment: @SamKirklandWA I forgot about the newlines in the string. I updated, please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing:

```
...
myString = myString.replace(/\s/g,'');
var jsonRegex = /.*{(.*)}.*/g;
var match = jsonRegex.exec(myString);
var jsonStr = match[1];
var myObject;
try {
  myObject = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
} catch (JSONException) {
  console.log('Error while parsing data: ', JSONException); 
}
```

Comment: Ok try this before my first line: myString = myString.replace(/\s/g,'');

Comment: The new line will remove all the white spaces (you can do it in regex101 editor).